# Get the Permanent unique device Id for android 10

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Since the android 10 has come it doesnot allow us to read the IMEI number of mobiles . Now what other number for mobiles can we have to uniquely identify them.

Comment: Hopefully, there is none. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids) for available options.